# How can i include a page in an IIS url rewrite rule (redirect)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, virtual-directory

I'm fairly new to url rewrite and trying to figure this thing out.
I have a website with the following structure:

http://localhost/virtualdirectory1/somepage.aspx?parameter1=x

http://localhost/virtualdirectory2/

Now I added a rule for a redirect (inbound rule):
matches pattern (regex) ^$ to make sure that if anybody goes to http://localhost that they are redirected to http://localhost/virtualdirectory1/somepage.aspx?parameter1=x
This also works fine for http://localhost/?paramter1=x which gets redirected properly.

This still allows me to approach http://localhost/virtualdirectory2/ directly.
However if the user goes to http://localhost/somepage.aspx?paramter1=x they are not redirected to the virtualdirectory1

Could give me some tips on how that can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this rule achieve your requirement? It will redirect both http://localhost and http://localhost/somepage.aspx?paramter1=x but it won't redirect http://localhost/.

```
   <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/somepage\.aspx)?$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="virtualdirectory1/somepage.aspx?parameter1=x" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```